# What UML tool is this file from?

Tags: uml

I've got a bunch of *.uml files in one legacy project that look like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Diagram>
  <ID>JS</ID>
  <OriginalElement>...</OriginalElement>
  <nodes />
  <settings layout="Hierarchic Group" zoom="0.8528951486697965" x="288.0" y="309.5" />
  <SelectedNodes />
  <Categories>
    <Category>Fields</Category>
  </Categories>
  <SCOPE>All</SCOPE>
  <VISIBILITY>PUBLIC</VISIBILITY>
</Diagram>`

Any idea which tool generated this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate Edition, not Community Edition) diagram files, used store UML diagrams generated by IntelliJ.

Here is an example shown in IntelliJ:
[image: IntelliJ and UML]

Here what the .uml file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Diagram>
    <ID>JAVA</ID>
    <OriginalElement />
    <nodes>
        <node x="-317.5" y="-101.0">com.artechra.Detail</node>
        <node x="-320.5" y="-195.0">com.artechra.Master</node>
    </nodes>
    <notes />
    <edges>
        <edge source="com.artechra.Master" target="com.artechra.Detail">
            <point x="0.0" y="0.0" />
            <point x="0.0" y="0.0" />
        </edge>
    </edges>
    <settings layout="Hierarchic Group" zoom="1.0" x="0.0" y="0.0" />
    <SelectedNodes />
    <Categories />
    <SCOPE>All</SCOPE>
    <VISIBILITY>private</VISIBILITY>
</Diagram>
```

According to the text that appears in each diagram, it's all "powered by" [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html) which may well be the generic markup format.

Comment: No sorry I was just working in IntelliJ IDEA and made an unintentional mistake when writing the question :) In fact I am trying to open those files in IDEA but it does nothing - the file just won't open. I would be surprise if it indeed were IDEA UML files...

Comment: Ah, easy mistake to make!  Could this be the version of IntelliJ you are using?  According to the [comparison matrix](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) this is only offered in Ultimate edition.  I've updated the answer to show the diagram and the file content in a simple example.

Comment: Hmm, I've got v13 Ultimate and double-clicking the file just does nothing. But thanks for trying that out for me.

Comment: That is odd.  Sorry, I'm not sure what's going on there then.  Might be worth pinging IDEA, I think this is their filetype.

Comment: IntelliJ behaves a bit strange in that it only shows diagrams that match the actual Java classes / Maven modules / ... in the project. That means, it won't show any diagram elements that are in the file, but not in the project. Maybe that's the reason of your confusion.